# Dynamically Change Content by clicking RibbonPane using Prism

Tags: wpf, prism, ribbon

I'm using Microsoft Ribbon and Prism to develop my application. I have in my main window 2 regions: one for the ribbon and the other to inject a view depending on the button clicked in my ribbon.

That works pretty good, but I would like to have the same functionality if I click a specific ribbon tab.

Has anyone done anything like this using Prism?

Comment: Post the code that you tried using button.

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted, here is the code using a Button. This code is in the VM of the Ribbon...when the button is clicked the event goes to OnShowConfiguration. This method load a new View in my GeneralContentRegion and also a new RibbonTab.

```
private void OnShowConfiguration()
   {
        loadView(PrismViewsNames.GeneralContentMainView, PrismRegionsNames.ContentRegion);
        loadView(PrismViewsNames.GeneralRibbonTab, PrismRegionsNames.RibbonMenuRegion);
    }

private void loadView(string viewToShow, string regionWhereToShow)
    {
        var regionManager = (RegionManager)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();

        var uri = new Uri(viewToShow, UriKind.Relative);
        regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionWhereToShow, uri);
    }
```

Myabe that helps you, Ayyappan Subramanian ;)